# Iterating and mapping over json and graph them into plotly graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

I am fetching a JSON object from Axios request. Now I am looking of **iterating** through and **mapping** them so that I can put this two value into a Plotly graph with x and y-axes.

I will really appreciate if someone give me an example please.

#### Return JSON data

```
[{"timestamp":"2018-0807T03:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":3.5999999046325684},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-07T18:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":1.5}, 
{"timestamp":"2018-07T23:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":3.0999999046325684}, 
{"timestamp":"20180808T15:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":9.800000190734863},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-08T16:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":5.099999904632568},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-09T15:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":8.800000190734863},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-09T16:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":8.199999809265137},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-10T12:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":6.199999809265137},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-18T14:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":8.199999809265137},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-19T21:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":7.199999809265137},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-20T11:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":5.099999904632568},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-20T16:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":7.699999809265137},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-22T10:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":5.099999904632568},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-23T10:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":11.300000190734863},
{"timestamp":"2018-08-23T15:00:00.000Z","wind_speed":9.300000190734863}]
```

Comment: You can find the example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly

Comment: Sameer Reza Khan Could you please tell me how can I iterate through and mapping it

Comment: create two empty array `x=[] and y=[]` , 
use `forEach` to iterate through your json and push timsestamp in x and windspeed in y, then pass x and y to plotly.

Comment: Sameer Reza Khan could you please give a code example

Comment: Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split it in two arrays, you could do it with a forEach as in this example:

```
var x = [];
var y = [];
yourJsonObject.forEach((item) => {
    x.push(item.timestamp);
    y.push(item.wind_speed);
});
```

Then use it in plotly as:

```
var plotly = require('plotly')('username','apiKey');

var data = [{x:x, y:y, stream:{token:'yourStreamtoken', maxpoints:200}}];
var graphOptions = {fileopt : "extend", filename : "nodenodenode"};

plotly.plot(data,graphOptions,function() {
  var stream = plotly.stream('yourStreamtoken', function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
  someReadableStream.pipe(stream);
});
```